# Enabling the second and third dropdownlistfor based on the value of first dropdownlistfor in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu

I have three DropDownLists. If a specific Value from my first DropDownList is chosen, the second Dropdownlist should be enabled. Example, if "Player 3" has been choosen, the other two DropDownList should be enabled, though, if "Player 2" is chosen the last DropDownList should be disabled and the second one enabled.

How can I easily do this? I am using MVC 3 EF model first.
This is my code in my view:

```
 <p>Player</p>
     <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.PlayerName,Model.SubjectTypes, "Choose player" , new { @class = "selectstyle" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PlayerName)
    </div>

    <p>Position</p>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PositionName, Model.Consultants, "Choose Position", new { @class = "selectstyle" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
    </div>

    <p>Team</p>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TeamName, Model.Teams, "Choose Team", new { @class = "selectstyle" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ContactPerson)
    </div>
```

Comment: Do you mean if a player has been chosen in the model or chosen on the client side? If it's the client side, then the answer below, using JQuery/Javascript, is the only way you can get any behavior. If it's on the server-side, you should be able to do this easily with a few if-statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `.change()` event of the first dropdown and then based on the currently selected value enable/disable the others:

```
$(function() {
    $('#PlayerName').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value == 'Player3') {
            $('#PositionName, #TeamName').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else if (value == 'Player2') {
            $('#PositionName').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#TeamName').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I've made that script, but my script dont seem to work. Ive used Mozilla Firefox Firebug, and scripts is getting loaded, though, once I select a player, the scripts dont seem to actually change my other dropdownlists to disabled.

Comment: @ps__, and when you debugged your script what was the value of the `value` variable inside the change method? Was it `Player3`? Or was it `Player2`? Or maybe it was something else which would explain why nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, It seems like the value actually is from our ID, i.e Player 2 has the ID 2. So I just changed the value to "value == '2'" instead of  "'Player2'". It was my bad. Thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following in jquery:

```
$('#PlayerName').change(function() 
{
    var id = $(this).val()
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPositions")',
        data:
            {
                "id": id,
            },
        success: function (data)
        {
           $("#positions").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Then i will have in the action controller:

```
public JsonResult GetPositions(int id)
{
  var positions = Repository.GetPositionsByPlayerId(id);
  var hmtl = positions.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
      Value = x.PositionID.ToString(),
      Text = x.Name
    });
  return new JsonResult { Data = html };
}
```

This will fill the values with all the postions related to that player.